# Symfony Session use session variables on Entity Forms

Tags: symfony, session

In Symfony2.7 we have fosuserbundle for user management in which an 'Organization' entity field is added for selecting user's organization from a list on registration form.

There is also another entity called 'Year' which is set by the Admin for setting and getting the active year.

We want: whenever user creates an entry using some entity based forms say 'Product', these two (organization id and year id) should be inserted along with the user provided data so that this can be isolated that this organization's user has created this product for this year.

Should we use session variables for achieving this? If so, what could be the best way and place to get and set session variables after successful logins?

Some snippets will help..

Thanks

Comment: you don't need session, look at setting the form as a service so you can inject the year and organization, and using form events you can edit the submitted data

Comment: Since I am new to Symfony..can you please explore the steps with some code ..Thanks..